# Uploading a pptx to Google Sites from G-Drive using its url

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I am automating a process to save documents in a G-Site. I have the url of a pptx and want to upload it, I am using the following code, but when I try to open the document in G-Sites it seems to be empty.

```
  function uploadfile () { 
  var url = my.pptxurl
  var name = getName(url);
  var site = SitesApp.getSite("mysite");
  var page = site.getAllDescendants()[0];
  var bloburl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  var blob = bloburl.setContentType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT);
  var attachment = page.addHostedAttachment(blob);
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving any error? Can you post the output of this line `console.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob())` ? Or some logs of the function execution would help.

Comment: @Aerials I don´t recieve any errors when I run it. The output from the console.log is {}. But when I log the URL it is the correct one from the file.

Comment: Do you know in which line our code is failing? Can you produce logs? Did you verify that there isn't another attachment with the same name ?

Comment: Can you confirm which sites you are using? Classic Sites or the new Sites?